# "Пропустите воду в течение 5 минут" или "пропускайте воду в течение 5 минут"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Увидел в инструкции к бытовому фильтру для очистки воды "Пропустите воду в течение 5 минут".
Как-то непривычно было читать. Хочется заменить на "Пропускайте воду в течение 5 минут", а еще лучше "спускайте" или "сливайте".

*Пропустите в течение 5 минут* воспринимается как если бы мне было нужно один раз в течение 5 минут пропустить воду, сделайте что-то в течение пяти минут.

*Пропускайте воду в течение 5 минут* воспринимается как если бы мне было нужно в течение 5 минут пропускать воду, делайте что-то в течение пяти минут.

Просто проверяю что я еще пока в своем уме. =)

Comment: Правильно: _в течени**е**_. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=В+течение&all=x

Comment: @slava1947 Мой косяк, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я с вашими рассуждениями полностью согласен: в инструкции употребили совершенный вид зря. А ещё присоединяюсь к поправке slava1947.